# How do I remove a common character from each element in my list?

Tags: python, html, list, beautifulsoup

I'm cleaning up my data after web scraping and the list has \n before each element.

SP500 = ['\nAAPL', '\nMSFT', '\nGOOG', '\nGOOGL', '\nAMZN', '\nTSLA'...]

How should I go about removing the \n from each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know it is always the same pattern, you can use str.removeprefix() available for python 3.9+, in your case:

```
SP500 = [value.removeprefix('\n') for value in SP500]
```

If you know it's always the same length, you can do:

```
SP500 = [value[2:] for value in SP500]
```

Comment: you should mention that `str.removeprefix` is available for python ≥ 3.9 ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
remove_char = ['\n']
SP500 = ['\nAAPL', '\nMSFT', '\nGOOG', '\nGOOGL', '\nAMZN', '\nTSLA']
SP500 = [''.join(x for x in string if not x in remove_char) for string in SP500]
```

every item in the remove_char list is deleted from your list

Comment: This will also delete it if the pattern appears in the middle of the string `"\nAZE\nRTY"` will be turned into `"AZERTY"` which is not wanted

Comment: Thank you so much! I just tested this out and it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a simple `lstrip()` to remove the character from the left:

```
[e.lstrip() for e in SP500]
```

or a `strip()` to remove it from left and right:

```
[e.strip() for e in SP500]
```

See also python [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#string-methods) in the docs `str.lstrip([chars])`

###### Example

```
SP500 = ['\nAAPL', '\nMSFT', '\nGOOG', '\nGOOGL', '\nAMZN', '\nTSLA']
SP500 = [e.lstrip() for e in SP500]
```

###### Output

```
['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'GOOGL', 'AMZN', 'TSLA']
```